# Reference triangle in semilogy plot tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

does someone know how to modify the macro in [Annotate / plot triangle with slope in PGFplots log log axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245686/annotate-plot-triangle-with-slope-in-pgfplots-log-log-axis-environment) to allow a reference triangle in semilog y scale? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/237192) to help us helping you. Which data do you have? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello! I didn't try anything yet, just removed in the macro for the loglog scale the computation of the logx but seems it is not good